# Matching character "/" in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

This is my first post and I am a newbie to Python. I am trying to get this to work.

```
string 1 = [1/0/1, 1/0/2]
string 2 = [1/1, 1/2]
```

Trying to check the string if I see two `/` then I just need to replace the `0` with `1` so it becomes `1/1/1` and `1/1/2`.

If I don't have  two `/` then I need to add one in along with a `1` and change it to the format `1/1/1` and `1/1/2` so string 2 becomes `[1/1/1,1/1/2]`

Ultimate goal is to get all strings match the pattern x/1/x. Thanks for all the Input on this.I tried this and it seems to work

```
for a in Port:
   if re.search(r'././', a):
     z.append(a.replace('/0/','/1/') )
   else:
     t1= a.split('/')
     if len(t1)>1 :
      t2= t1[0] + "/1/" + t1[1]
      z.append(t2)
```

few lines are there to take care of some exceptions but seems to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

The regex pattern for identifying a `/` is just `\/`

Comment: There is no need to escape a forward slash in Python. The forward slash character is not a special character in the RegEx standards nor is it considered a special character in Python's implementation of RegEx. However, in some languages (such as JavaScript and, in some cases, PHP), escaping a forward slash would be necessary. Nonetheless, in Python, it is nothing and escaping will only mess up the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

This could be solved rather simply using the built in string functions without having to add all of the overhead and additional computational time caused by using the RegEx engine.

For example:

```
# The string to test:
sTest = '1/0/2'

# Test the string:
if(sTest.count('/') == 2):
    # There are two forward slashes in the string
    # If the middle number is a 0, we'll replace it with a one:
    sTest = sTest.replace('/0/', '/1/')
elif(sTest.count('/') == 1):
    # One forward slash in string
    # Insert a 1 between first portion and the last portion:
    sTest = sTest.replace('/', '/1/')
else:
    print('Error: Test string is of an unknown format.')
# End If
```

If you really want to use RegEx, though, you could simply match the string against these two patterns: `\d+/0/\d+` and `\d+/\d+(?!/)` If matching against the first pattern fails, then attempt to match against the second pattern. Then, you can use a either grouping, splitting, or simply calling `.replace()` (like I'm doing above) to format the string as you need.

**EDIT**: for clarification, I'll explain the two patterns:

Pattern 1: `\d+/0/\d+` could essentially be read as "match any number (consisting of one (1) or more digits) followed by a forward slash, a zero (0), another forward slash and then followed by any number (consisting of one (1) or more digits).

Pattern 2: `\d+/\d+(?!/)` could be read as "match any number (consisting of one (1) or more digits) followed by a forward slash and any other number (consisting of one (1) or more digits) which is then **NOT** followed by another forward slash." The last part in this pattern could be a little confusing because it uses the negative lookahead abilities of the RegEx engine.

If you wanted to add stricter rules to these patterns to make sure there are not any leading or trailing non-digit characters, you could add `^` to the start of the patterns and `$` to the end, to signify the start of the string and the end of the string respectively. This would also allow you to remove the lookahead expression from the second pattern (`(?!/)`). As such, you would end up with the following patterns: `^\d+/0/\d+$` and `^\d+/\d+$`.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/rE6oN2/1
Click code generator on the left side. You get:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\d/1/\d')
test_str = u"1/1/2"

re.search(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing this. I just tried using the following and it seems to do the trick. Might not be optimum way of doing it                                                          for a in Port:

   if re.search(r'././', a):
     z.append(a.replace('/0/','/1/') )
   else:
     t1= a.split('/')
     if len(t1)>1 :
      t2= t1[0] + "/1/" + t1[1]
      z.append(t2)